# How to return a reference to something inside a moved box?

Tags: rust

I want to store a Box in a map, and take the address of the contents of the Box and hand it out to C code. This is why I don't just store the value directly in the map, as map values move when a map grows.

I'd like a function that returns a reference to the contents of the Box, that I can use in Rust code and either use as-is in Rust code, or convert the returned reference to a raw pointer for C.

This code illustrates what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't work for obvious reasons. However, it's not clear to me how to fix it.

```
use std::collections::{HashMap};

fn box_and_ref<'a>(map: &'a mut HashMap<String, Box<Vec<u8>>>) -> &'a Vec<u8> {
    let v = vec!{b'h', b'e', b'l', b'l', b'o'};
    let b = Box::new(v);
    let r = b.as_ref();
    map.insert("foo".to_string(), b);
    r
}

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<String, Box<Vec<u8>>> = HashMap::new();

    let v = box_and_ref(&mut map);
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8cc7f770603d7871753e592adb30de8b)

Comment: Err, wouldn't you be able to fix your current compiling error with `map["foo"].as_ref()`? After all, that's the new location of your `Box`.

Comment: I think so, but now I have to do an unecessary lookup of the value in the map. All I really want is the address (pointer) to the heap value that I know is in that Box. I could do this "safely" with unsafe. Is this just one of those times where you have to just shrug and do it the rust way?

Comment: Also because the key is moved into the map, you need to copy the key (String in this case) as well. I'm going to try to do this with the hashmap entry API (I thought it was still unstable, but that's on hashset only).

Comment: @Eloff most of the entry API has been stable since Rust 1.0.0, and what we have now is certainly enough for this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any “avoid double lookup” issues, use the [entry API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html):

```
fn box_and_ref<'a>(map: &'a mut HashMap<String, Box<Vec<u8>>>) -> &'a Vec<u8> {
    let v = vec!{b'h', b'e', b'l', b'l', b'o'};
    let b = Box::new(v);
    map.entry("foo".to_string()).or_insert(b)
}
```

Comment: This answers the question, but as soon as I tried to apply it to the real problem I was foiled because it seems you can't take a reference to anything in a map behind a Mutex, as the MutexGuard lives only as long as you hold the lock. I'm not sure what the fix is there, but I'm considering just swapping the Box for a raw pointer obtained from Box::leak and calling it a day.

Comment: If your borrow of the box's contents were to outlive your borrow of the map, consider what happens if the map is dropped? The box (and its contents) would also be dropped, its memory deallocated and your reference would dangle. The statically verifiable safe solution is to borrow the map for the duration of your reference to the contents; a runtime verifiable safe solution would be to share ownership, e.g. with `Rc`.  Otherwise you are introducing your own guarantees about lifetimes that neither the compiler nor runtime are able to verify: which is what raw pointers and `unsafe` are for.